# How to make a XML/PHP file returning custom field data from page

Tags: php, xml

I want to make a make a Ajax search bar that uses an XML file that will be made from the acf of the users profile page that gets return from the PHP template. 
How do I go about creating an XML file in php.

Comment: Hi Henry! Is there a reason you're doing it this way? It seems pretty complicated if you want to search through the fields in a user's profile.

Comment: The reason I turned to this was because the site I'm building actually adds new users via admin only, no frontend fields. Admin will add acf fields to each new user they see fit. However the problem I ran into is that for every new user, the post id is set to that of admins. Resulting in a search only producing of admins posts and not of the actual user when they search for their items, being the acf fields in the search bar. Unless you know of way to change the author of in the post table ???

Comment: I would modify your question to ask about the issue you're having rather than the workaround solution you've come up with. I think there's a better way.